# subtracting times in vb

Tags: vb.net

I want to subtract 18 years from a VB date object.
Here's the code example:

```
Dim someVar
DirectCast(pcontrol, DateTimePicker).Value = Date.Now.Subtract(someVar)
```

someVar value is ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It can seem odd, but try using `AddYears`, but with a negative number:

```
With DirectCast(pcontrol, DateTimePicker)
  .Value = .Value.AddYears(-18)
End With
```

or as MarkJ points out, trying to subtract it from now:

```
With DirectCast(pcontrol, DateTimePicker)
  .Value = Now.AddYears(-18)
End With
```

Comment: +1 Although I don't think you've quite answered the question. If you look at the sample code in the question, I think the OP is looking for `.Value = Date.Now.AddYears(-18)`

Comment: @tawfik Do you want to subtract 18 years from the current value in the control (as in this answer), or do you want to subtract 18 years from the current date by  the system clock (as in your question)?

Comment: MarkJ, am not going to copy paste the snippet, i wanted the method it slipped out of my head. thanks for your interest.

Comment: @tawfik No problem, just being obsessive. I've been reviewing code today and I may be stuck in that mode :)